# Win32 C++ SetLayeredWindowAttributes is either fully opaque or fully transparent; nothing in between

Tags: c++, winapi, createwindow

So I have a 2nd Window created within my program like:

```
#define WINDOW_CLASS_NAME "WINCLASSFULL"

WNDCLASSEX winclass;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

some function {

HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL);

// first fill in the window class stucture

winclass.cbSize         = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
winclass.style          = CS_DBLCLKS | CS_OWNDC | 
                          CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
winclass.lpfnWndProc    =WndProc;
winclass.cbClsExtra = 0;                        //reserve data space
winclass.cbWndExtra = 0;                        //
winclass.hInstance  = hInstance;                //set instance of application
winclass.hIcon      = NULL;
winclass.hCursor    = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);         //load cursor type
winclass.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH); //set background brush
winclass.lpszMenuName   = NULL;                               
winclass.lpszClassName  = WINDOW_CLASS_NAME;                 //set Windows class name
winclass.hIconSm        = NULL;

hWnd= CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED,                  // extended style
                            WINDOW_CLASS_NAME,     // class
                            "Demo", // title
                            WS_POPUP,
                            x,y,
                            width,height,
                            NULL,
                            NULL, 
                            hInstance,// instance of this application
                            NULL))) // extra creation parms

}
```

Now my issue is if I apply

Where 255 can be anything between 1-255

```
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd,RGB(0,0,0),255,LWA_COLORKEY|LWA_ALPHA)
```

The window is fully opaque i can't see anything behind it

This is fully transparent:

```
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd,RGB(0,0,0),0,LWA_COLORKEY|LWA_ALPHA)
```

How can I get

```
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd,RGB(0,0,0),128,LWA_COLORKEY|LWA_ALPHA)
```

To work - i.e. so I can partially see my window on top; and partially see window behind it. I've checked the doco on MSDN here but I'm obviously missing something [Refer Microsoft Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Why are all these people compiling Windows applications in 2012 without `UNICODE` defined? And why are you including `LWA_COLORKEY` if you're not setting a transparency color?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967003/setlayeredwindowattributes-not-working-on-windows-7 contains a bit of useful info; it's NOT a duplicate of this question, but touches on the same kind of issue.

Comment: Did you read the "Community Additions" at the link you provided? I think that it gives you the answer that you shouldnt combine `LWA_COLORKEY` and `LWA_ALPHA`.

Comment: No repro, I get a transparent window with just the borders and caption visible.  As expected, you made black the color key.  The 2nd version produces a completely invisible window, as expected.  The 3rd version produces partially visible borders and fully transparent interior, as expected.  Document the Windows version and make it clear exactly *where* you put the SetLayeredWindowAttributes() call.

Comment: Ok yes I know it should be unicode but updating a project from the beginning of time and unicode breaks it right now for some reason...another to fix later...On the net I had seen many purpotedly working example which has used LWA_ALPHA+LWA_COLORKEY. But according to link provided it doesn't work the same in Windows 7. If I use SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd,RGB(0xff,0xff,0xff), 100, LWA_ALPHA); still doesn't work for me, If I create a completely new project it works, any ideas what else might break this?

Comment: No ideas off the top of my head what might break this. Do as Hans suggests and post the code that contains the `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` call so that we can see it *in context*.

Answer (score 3):

Try to specify only `LWA_ALPHA,` not both `LWA_COLORKEY` and `LWA_ALPHA`