# SetLayeredWindowAttributes to make CEF transparent not working on Windows XP

Tags: windows, winapi, google-chrome, windows-xp, chromium-embedded

I use [SetLayeredWindowAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with LWA_COLORKEY to replace a color (#ff00ff) with transparency, in order to achieve transparent background in the [CEF1](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) example.

It works well on 7/Vista.
On Windows XP, the function succeeds, but the color remains opaque.

My code to create the main window:

```
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow) {
  HWND hWnd;
  hInst = hInstance;
  hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_COMPOSITED, szWindowClass, szTitle,
                 WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0,
                 CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

WndProc for the main window:

```
switch (message) {
case WM_CREATE: {
  ...
  info.SetTransparentPainting(TRUE);
  info.SetAsChild(hWnd, rect);

  // Create the new child browser window
  CefBrowser::CreateBrowser(info,
      static_cast<CefRefPtr<CefClient> >(g_handler),
      url_to_pageWithMagentaBackground, settings);

  SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, RGB(0xff, 0x00, 0xff), 0xff, LWA_COLORKEY);
```

Html displayed:

```
<style type="text/css">html { background: #ff00ff; }</style>
```

Note these points:

- It does work on XP with LWA_ALPHA (makes whole window semi-transparent),
  but not with LWA_COLORKEY
- When I connect to the XP through Remote Desktop, I do see the transparency as expected!

Can someone explain this please?

Comment: Maybe your native display on the XP machine is not 24 bit and so the background color does not match the alpha key exactly?

Comment: Indeed, if I change "Color Quality" in the Windows Display Settings from highest (32 bit) to medium (16 bit), transparency works!
So how can I make it work on the native display?

Comment: I guess you need to work out what the actual RGB values are that the color ends up being rendered as. Maybe GetPixel could tell you?

Comment: GetPixel returns the same values (e.g. ff,00,ff) on both xp modes (Hi/Mi color) and on Windows 7.
I inserted it in UIT_RunGetImageTest in the CEF sample application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SetLayeredWindowAttributes not working on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967003/setlayeredwindowattributes-not-working-on-windows-7)